# Another how do I use LINQ to Enumerate Dictionaries

Tags: linq

Thank you to all the folks who answered and contributed to my last question. I have run into another interesting incarnation of a LINQ question... so like before...

I have the following

```
const String A_CONVERSATION = "AD Channels";
const String NOT_REPUTABLE = "AD Resolution";
const String DO_NOT_KNOW = "Capture Input";

private enum Properties
{ MyHow, Thats, It }

List<String> MyList = new List<string> 
{ 
    A_CONVERSATION, 
    NOT_REPUTABLE, 
    DO_NOT_KNOW
}


private Dictionary <Properties, String> PropertyToString;
private Dictionary <String, Properies> StringToProperty;
```

How can I use LINQ to populate each of the dictionaries so that I can use the following? Is there a one line LINQ statement that would populate each?

```
Properties MyResult1 = StringToProperty[A_CONVERSATION];
String MySResult2 = PropertyToString[Properties.It];
```

I specifically would like to use the actaull property to index in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing this is what you want...

In two statements (one could be merged I guess via some lookup somehow - but I didn't think it was that relevant - not everything has to be in one line:)

```
var properties = ((Properties[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Properties))).ToList();
var propertyToString = properties.Zip(MyList, (p, s) => new { Prop = p, Text = s }).ToDictionary(x => x.Prop, x => x.Text);
var stringToProperty = properties.Zip(MyList, (p, s) => new { Prop = p, Text = s }).ToDictionary(x => x.Text, x => x.Prop);
```

I deliberately separated the makings of the enum list - for clarity - you can move that into one line if you'd like.

Comment: Will this use the strange list of strings List<String> MyList...?

Comment: you have the `MyList` in the `Zip` - not sure exactly what's the 'dilemma'?

Comment: it makes one-on-one first-to-first, second-to-second...sort it out if differently - or that's what could be done from the Q

Comment: OK did not know.. I'm a new to LINQ stuff. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: just try it out - I don't see much of the point though :) but should work - or for excersize, or for fun

Comment: I get a key not found when I ran my program. I actually have a property PFD which is suppose to correspond to 'PIN_FILE'. So the string does not match the name of the property.